# How to prevent truncation in PHP error logs

Tags: php, wordpress, apache

I have some errors coming from Wordpress and ending up in the Apache server error log file. I noticed that the errors are truncated and it's the most important part that I can't see because of this. What's super strange is that when I increase `php_admin_value[log_errors_max_len]` (currently at 8000) I just get the same truncated log multiple times in a single log message (see below). If I increase it even more I'm getting even more copies of the same error. I'm lost now which layer (WP? PHP? Apache?) is doing the truncating and how can I fix it.

You can see a single log message here:

```
[Sat Oct 28 14:29:10.875915 2023] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 20448:tid 140469874956032] [client 37.191.54.101:0] AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: modified_date was called incorrectly. Order properties should not be accessed directly. Backtrace: require('wp-blog-header.php'), requir
e_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'), do_action('template_redirect'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, WC_AJAX::do_wc_ajax, do_action('wc_ajax_checkout'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, WC_AJAX::checkout, WC_Checkout->process_checkout, WC_Checkout->p
rocess_order_without_payment, WC_Order->payment_complete, do_action('woocommerce_payment_complete'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, WooCommerce_Simba_PrintOrders_1_0->woocommerce_payment_complete, WooCommerce_Simba_PrintOrders_1_0->print_order_or_schedule, WooCommer
ce_Simba_PrintOrders_1_0->print_go, WooCommerce_Simba_PrintOrders_1_0->woocommerce_process_order, WooCommerce_Simba_PrintOrders_Sources_1_0->getdocument_woocommerce_pips_packing_slip, WooCommerce_Simba_PrintOrders_Sources_1_0->_pips_generate_output, WPO\\WC\\PDF_Invoices\\Docume
nts\\Order_Document->get_pdf, ...PHP message: modified_date was called incorrectly. Order properties should not be accessed directly. Backtrace: require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'), do_action('template_redirect'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP
_Hook->apply_filters, WC_AJAX::do_wc_ajax, do_action('wc_ajax_checkout'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, WC_AJAX::checkout, WC_Checkout->process_checkout, WC_Checkout->process_order_without_payment, WC_Order->payment_complete, do_action('woocommerce_payment_complete
'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, WooCommerce_Simba_PrintOrders_1_0->woocommerce_payment_complete, WooCommerce_Simba_PrintOrders_1_0->print_order_or_schedule, WooCommerce_Simba_PrintOrders_1_0->print_go, WooCommerce_Simba_PrintOrders_1_0->woocommerce_process_order,
 WooCommerce_Simba_PrintOrders_Sources_1_0->getdocument_woocommerce_pips_packing_slip, WooCommerce_Simba_PrintOrders_Sources_1_0->_pips_generate_output, WPO\\WC\\PDF_Invoices\\Documents\\Order_Document->get_pdf, ...', referer: https://beadingschool.com/checkout/
```

Notice that the truncated text ("Order_Document->get_pdf, ...") appears 2 times in the log message.

Comment: Did you notice **modified_date was called incorrectly. Order properties should not be accessed directly** ?

Comment: i wonder is the code using `error_log()` ? which  is not binary safe. the error message will be truncated by null character..

Comment: `AH01071` looks like apache is logging the php-fpm.

Comment: @KenLee Yes I did, but what's not visible in the output is where this error is coming from as the stacktrace is going from high to low level.

Comment: @RaymondNijland This is coming from Wordpress error handling.. I'm not sure if it's using error_log().

Comment: @Butthosenewbuttonsthough.. done. this time it displays correctly